# Save collection data into a session Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I have a question, I would like to save my data from 2 collection selects into a session so after use this data for create suppliers or forwarders etc.

The reason for that it's because I want to login with a user and this user can select a client and a role save this data into a session and use it for create with this data supplier and other things.

**Just I have my two collection in my navbar menu application layout:**

```
<%= collection_select(:client, :client_id, Client.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Escoge empresa", class: "form-control")%>
<%= collection_select(:user, :role_id, Role.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Escoge cliente", class: "form-control")%>
```

so I don't know how to do that because I think I'm going to need create a controller with an action ? and use this action into my collection? I'm not sure just I need a little orientation.

Regards ! and thanks for the time. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You create form with those two selects
- You submit this form which will call an action in your controller
- In this action you store the `id` of the client and user (don't store full records, only store their IDs to keep the session small and avoid troubles with deserialized records)

In your SelectionController (or whatever you will call it)

```
def create
session[:selected_user_id] = params[:user_id]
session[:selected_client_id] = params[:client_id]
render(:whatever_you_want_to_render)
end
```

- Add a helper method to retrieve the user and client.

In your application controller:

```
helper_method :selected_user, :selected_client

def selected_user
  @selected_user ||= User.find(session[:selected_user_id])
end

def selected_client
  ...
end
```

Parameter names depend on how you build your form. Action name as well. But this should get you started. Otherwise ask more detailed question.

Comment: Thank you ! Now I understand better !